# virtualenv creates a thousand processes in cygwin

Tags: python, cygwin, virtualenv

So i attempted to run a virtual environment, but the command,

```
virtualenv venv
```

Started about 1000 python processes and never completed. Is this normal or some bug?
I am working in cygwin on windows 10, using
 - python 3.7.4
 - virtualenv 16.6.1
 - pip 19.1.1
This is the first command i attempted to run after installing a fresh python.

Comment: This is not normal. Does `virtualenv --version` work? You could consult the article [Pipenv & Virtual Environments](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/).

Comment: Yes ```virtualenv --version``` was used to find the version specified above. And that was the guide i followed in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is an issue regarding python 3.7.4 and 3.8.x which has defined `sys._base_executable`. This change caused the infinite loop of process creations.

See [Github Issue](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/1380) for more information and updates, as of 10th of July 2019 the issue is not resolved yet. Maintainers of virtualenv are aware of the issue.

Update: as of 14th of July 2019, the problem have been solved.